# Adding data to MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add info to my data base MySQL from my iPhone app, through the use of the PHP code that follows:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["var1"])  && isset($_GET["var2"])){
    $User = $_GET["var1"];
    $Password = $_GET["var2"];
    $conexion = conectdb();

    $result = insertUser($User, $Password, $conexion);
}

function conectdb(){
    $host=“http://myExample.com";
    $bd=“pruebabd”;
    $usuario=“StackOverFlow”;
    $password=“thisIsMyPassword”;

    $conexion = mysql_connect($host, $usuario, $password);
    mysql_select_db($bd, $conexion);

    return $conexion;
}

function insertUser($User, $Password, $conexion) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pruebabd (User, Password) VALUES ('{$User}’,’{$Password}’)”, $conexion);
    mysql_close($conexion);
    echo 1;
}
?>
```

My hosting works as a Plesk Hosting.

When I run my project, it doesn't work.

For the field `$host`, should I write the name of my domain? What should I write in `$host`?

I called to the enterprise who sold me the domain and hosting, but they told me that it is not possible to make this operation because it works as "Plesk Hosting". They told me that I need to change my hosting to `CPanel` Linux. Is it true?

Comment: When you say "doesnt work" what exactly happens? nothing? have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The row is not inserted? The page is not reached? The code is not executed? Any error displayed?

Comment: What are you writing the php in, MS Word, or is this just a copy-paste mistake? You cannot use those kinds of curly quotes, only straight single or double quotes or -  in sql statements - backticks.

Comment: The bd is not reached. The row is not inserted into my db. I'm executing my code from XCode and it does not show any error. I wrote a conditional in the PHP to validate if the bd is reached but it's never reached. @castis

Comment: @jeroen i´m writing the PHP code in TextEdit (mac-making it plain text). The original quotes are straight...